# Changing Form Size in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

good morning all :)

was wondering if anyone can tell me how come I cant get my windows form size to go to 1280x 768 in vs 2008?

My resolution that I am working on is 1024x768..but the computer that I am going to be running this program on is a wide screen..1280x768.

I try to change it in properties but it keeps defaulting back to 1036x760.

Comment: C#? VB? WPF? WinForms? Silverlight? Please provide tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Size` property in code, like this: (In the constructor, or anywhere else)

```
Size = new Size(1280, 768);
```

However, it would probably be better to simply make the form maximized.  (Set the form's WindowStyle in the properties window)